# My new employer is asking to join before the end of notice period despite already agreeing on a start date

Tags: new-job, resignation, notice-period

I've been working in a firm for the last 3 years. Two weeks ago, I interviewed for a position in a new company and was selected.

My current employers notice period policy is either 2 months notice or 1 month notice plus the loss of a months pay.

I had clearly mentioned the 2 month notice period to my new employer. They were okay with the 2 month notice period and asked me to confirm the offer letter. Now I have resigned, and the new employer's HR is asking for me to join within a month. However, this is not possible for me at all due to my responsibilities at my current workplace.

How can I communicate to my new employer that I am not able to join within a month for the agreed upon reasons?

Comment: Can you go back to the new employer and clarify why they would like you to start in one month? It could be that they have not edited a standard acceptance letter rather than that they desperately require you to start for a new project

Comment: She said, a new project is going to start, so please try to come with in a month. But it is not possible to me.

Comment: S.K. - thanks. Personally, I would look to do what I can to please my new employer rather than my current one. Of course, its a fine line to not burn bridges as you never know who you will meet again in life. Can I ask WHY it is not possible to leave your current one within 1 month? What penalties are attached to doing so?

Comment: If your new employer was aware you needed two months, then it's fair to everyone involved to remain at the old position for two months. The world is full of high priority projects that aren't going to get done on schedule. Better to honor the spirit of your agreement, letting the new employer know you're in the habit of keeping your promises.

Comment: Hi @S.K I edited your post to try to focus it on the issue a bit more and to make it a little easier to read. Hopefully the question still resembles what you wanted to ask. Welcome to the site and good luck!

Comment: I had asked three times to new employer before putting my resignation. They were OK with 2 month Notice Period.

Comment: I hope you can clarify how you'll loose a months pay. Obviously, if you work 1-month less time (1-month compared to 2-months), you'll receive less pay because of the month you will not work. But, do you mean that if you only give 1-month notice, you will also have to forfit a month's-pay for time you did work... essentially meaning you would be working your final month of work without pay (unpaid).

Comment: ... If that is the case, you didn't mention if you are a "Contractor" or an "Employee", or what country you live in. In the US, it would almost certainly not be allowed for an employer to require an employee to work a month without pay, regardless of any employment-contract provisions. In fact it may not be legal for an employer to suggest/threaten to an employee such an arragnment. This would probably not apply for Non-employee worker (contractor).

Comment: Do you not have a letter of offer from the new company stating a start date two months in the future? You should never resign from your current job without a written offer.

Comment: The offer letter had a start date, right?  If they need you badly enough, then they should be willing to pay the one month's pay penalty with your old employer to make that happen.  This is standard.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this sort of arrangement.  In the US, a 2 week notice is sufficient.  Can you explain how the 1 or 2 month notice affects things?  My guess is that something is lost in translation or implication somewhere.  I see other comments that also are not clear on how that works.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> How can I communicate to my new employer that I am not able to join
>   within a month for the agreed upon reasons?

This is easy.

You explain to them that you are very eager to join your new company, and start working on the new project as soon as possible.

You explain to them that, as they agreed to before their job offer was accepted, you are committed to a 2 month notice period with your former employer. You know that your new company wouldn't want departing employees to renege on their commitments, so you know that they will understand your situation.

You further explain that you would be happy to join in 1 month, if they would agree to pay for the "loss of a month's pay" you would have to forfeit back to your old company.

Then you ask which way they would like to proceed.

Comment: This is basically the "buy out your contract" option.  You basically make both the employee and their employeer "whole" as the new employeer.

Comment: Good advice, but maybe I misreading the question.  Two months notice or one month with loss of a month's pay.  Yeah your only working one month so of course your losing one month's pay.  But you start a month earlier at new job which hopefully is better paid?  Is there an issue?

Comment: @MarkChapman I think he means you have to work the 1 month for free to make up for cutting the notice short.

Comment: Wouldn't you just walk out then, leave and lose 2 months or work 1 month and lose 2, sounds like you resign the minute you get paid and go,having arranged to start new job next day for continuity.

Comment: @MarkChapman -  When I first read the question, I thought that reading it as you did, while being perfectly logical, would be too much "stating the obvious", so I then figured it meant if "he/she" (S.K.) took the 1-month notice option, their final month of work would be unpaid. But of course they could have meant it either way. It should definately be clarified.

Comment: @Mark: "Forfeit a month's pay" is not the same as working the next month for free.  If you trigger pay forfeiture, they have many options, including deducting it from owed vacation time, reversing a previous deposit, garnishing a retirement plan (if they've contributed to it).  Not to mention blacklisting and possible legal action.

Comment: @Ben Well that was what I was talking about as work 1 month, lose 2. I think if I was making a move from an employer like this the holiday would be all used at time of resignation.  I would dread to live in any country where the employer could ctrl-z paid salary or pension plans, just about impossible in UK and likely Europe.  Legal action also, too expensive to be worth it here, but again YMMV.

Comment: @BenVoigt Reversing a bank deposit? What country are you in?

Comment: @Brian: USA. Have you ever read the fine print on a direct deposit authorization?  It generally gives permission to move money in the opposite direction when a mistake has been made (if a typo was made in the amount, or a payment was made to the wrong account).  Combine that with a signed contract agreeing to the penalty, and I wouldn't want to bet against the same ACH mechanism being used to recover the penalty.  Or have it classified as a mistaken deposit and reversed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not saying that it's technically impossible, I'm saying that it's illegal. Unless you're a real independent contractor, wages are inviolate. No matter how bad you mess up, you always, always get paid through the end of your last day or you will have a field day in court.

Comment: @BrianGordon: It sounds as if you are claiming that the forfeiture is an onerous and void term of the employment contract.  That could be, but it's a completely different topic from Mark's recommendation to fail to pay it by walking away without notice.  Either they owe wages for the last month worked (because the forfeiture is illegal), or they don't owe wages for the month immediately preceding early departure, in which case the deposit was made without any obligation to do so, and might be "corrected".

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager _"Wouldn't you just walk out then"_ nice catch, but maybe it would be just illegal.

Comment: @Lohoris - It's not illegal, maybe breach of contract, but is it worth their while pursuing you for it?

Comment: Another possibility is that the new company may be prepared for them to enter the new job at whatever date 4-8 weeks in the future would be most convenient for the employee and former employer.  If the old employer is five weeks away from finishing a major project, and then starting a new project that would require four weeks of training before an employee could start doing useful work, it may be better for *both* the old and new employer to have the person switch jobs three weeks sooner than scheduled.

Answer (score 7):

It's not complicated: You should reply to your new employer and give your new employer the reasons you stated in your post.

If I were you, I would add that I am quite eager to join but that I need to live to my responsibility to ensure a smooth transition on behalf of my current employer and unfortunately, the process is still going on, however much I'd like to speed it up and despite the steps I have taken to speed it up. I'd tell the new employer that I am playing it by ear on a day to day basis and if it turns out that yes, I can actually quit before my official date, I'll be glad to make immediate arrangements to do just that. In the meantime, I would provide any other assistance that is within my power. I would add as a final thought that I am stuck and stuck good, as I am in the midst of training others to take over my responsibilities even as we speak.

Comment: You have a responsibility to your current employer that is clearly given in their notice policy. You are now fulfilling that responsibility.

Comment: Ollie Jones: Thanks for the conciseness of your comment  :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the hinging piece on this is the phrase "confirm the offer later".  Now, I'm not sure if contract law works the same in India as it does in the United States, but here (I'll just presume that it does) an employer can get in hot water for trying to change the terms of an employment offer **after the employee has accepted the offer**, IF the employee then takes actions that would not have occurred if there was no offer.  "Actions" might include resigning from the old position, relocating, and so forth.

If the employee makes an offer, and it's accepted, and then the employer decides to withdraw the offer, the applicant-employee may be able to recover damages in court.

S.K., have you OFFICIALLY accepted (confirmed, as you put it) the offer?

Friend S.K, it's sounding like you are afraid that the new employer will withdraw the offer - which is reasonable, if you don't comply with the request to  start a month earlier.  I don't know what recourse specifically is available in India - you'd have to contact an attorney for that.  My own take on the situation is that if you agreed to one situation, but now the new employer is pressuring you to accept another situation, that's a bad precedent right from the outset.  You might consider finding another place to work that will treat you better.